# Open port in linux with java application

Tags: java, linux, port

I've a java application that creates a socketserver in a port.
I test my application in a windows machine, and runs correctly, but when I test it in a linux machine, the port is not listening.

Is there any way to open a port specifically in a linux machine?

I run 'netstat' command, and the port I use in my application doesn't appear.
It doesn't throw any exception.
I'm trying to connect from another machine to the application, and the connection is refused.

Sincerely, I don't know why it doesn't run...

help please.

thanks,
david

Comment: There's no difference between the 2.  Show us your code to see what you're trying to do

Comment: the only difference is that in the windows machine i run a ".jar" and in the linux machine i run a ".sar", but it don't affect the type of operating system, but in the jboss.

Comment: If you can not listen on a specified port, the server socket would throw out a exception, have you got that exception? Or if you listen okay, the netstat should show up the port you are listening on.

Answer (score 3):

What is the port number you're trying to open ?

If it's below 1024, then only the root user can open it or grant access to it.

Comment: the port number is 1234.
i'm the root user

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your code is actually being executed?  Your comment about the code being in a `.sar` file implies that you aren't executing it directly, but are deploying it to jboss.  Maybe it is not deployed correctly?  Have you tried putting some logging statements (or even `System.out.println` statements) before and after the ServerSocket is created?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference on Windows and Linux. Can you post an exception-stacktrace, that you most likely get?

The possibilities that are likely are, that your chosen port is already occupied (on Linux usually some services are running) or that you try to bind a port below 1024, that is only allowed for root.

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same. Does it throw an exception on linux? Maybe the target port is occupied already.

**Edit:** Maybe your code successfully binds to the port but the Linux firewall blocks the incoming connections?

**Edit 2:** Maybe your Linux JBoss configuration differs and your code which contains the initialization for the ServerSocket is not automatically executed.

Comment: the problem isn't in my code, because it works in a windows machine.
the firewall isn't the problem, because it doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

use netstat -napt to check (I don't know which arguments you used).

Comment: i use "netstat -na" and "netstat -na | grep 1234"

Answer (score 0):

Like Johan Buret said if you are trying to open a port below 1024 you will have to run your program as root or sudo.

if you are running a distro like ubuntu where you are not root and root is not enabled do the following:
sudo java SocketServer

if you are a regular user and can su to root fedora/redhat based distros run this:
su -
(prompt for root's password)
java SocketServer

Comment: i tried it, but it throws a "ClassNotFoundException: SocketServer"

Comment: Are you using Sun Java or gcj?  gcj is a open source implementation of java that I have always had trouble with.  Try installing the Sun java jdk and jre.

Comment: You mean java.net.ServerSocket right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting from the same machine, to rule out firewall issues?

You can also use telnet to check if the port's open or not

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

(will give connection refused if the port isn't open)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the JBoss SAR is not configured correctly to start your server. Try the following:

- Run the JAR file from the Linux command line (as you have successfully on Windows)
- Install the SAR file into a Windows JBoss installation and see if you get the same issue as on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Is [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinux) enabled? Try disabling it: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Answer (score 0):

Replying to this old post; for benefit of new comers.

Similar problem was being faced by one of my team members. Not sure what your specific problem could be; for us the problem was small and stupid. The path separator for Unix is colon ":" while for windows it is semi-colon ";".  While calling the socket server java process from java application, please make sure to use [java.io.File.pathSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) so that the RunTime code works on both Windows and Unix environment.